# Cannot read property add() of undefined Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

There is a problem with the `game.state.add()` function. For some reason `game` is undefined:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at Object.init (main.js:51) at main.js:58

This is my code:

```
var socket; // global bir socket değişkeni.
    socket = io.connect(); // server a bağlantı isteği gönderir.
                           //Server bağlantı isteğini dinler ve clientlara başarılı olursa geri "connect" mesajını emitler.

    //Oyunun ekrana oturması için boyutları ayarlıyoruz.Browserla ilgili.
    var canvas_width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
    var canvas_height = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;   
    //Oyunumuzu belirlediğimiz divin içinde yaratıyoruz.
    var game = new Phaser.Game(canvas_width,canvas_height,Phaser.CANVAS,'gameDiv');

    var gameProperties = {
      //oyunun gerçek boyutları.oyun dünyasının genişliği ve uzunluğu.
      gameWidth:4000,
      gameHeight:4000,
    }

    //Oyunun ana state i.
    var main = function(game){

    };
    main.prototype ={
    preload:function(){

    },
    create:function(){ // oyun yaratıldığında çağrılır.
    console.log("Client yaratıldı.")
    //serverdan connect mesajı gelince onSocketConnected fonksiyonunu çalıştır.
    socket.on("connect",onSocketConnected); //serverdan gelecek connect mesajı için dinler.Socket.io bir client
                                            // servera bağlandığında otomatik olarak connect mesajını client a gönderir.
                                            //serverın clientlara mesaj göndermesine "emit"  denir.

    },    
    }
    function onSocketConnected(){
      console.log("Sunucuya bağlanıldı.")    
    };

    var gameBootStrapper = {
         init:function(gameContainerId){
             game.state.add('main',main);   //error here
             game.state.start('main');
         }
    };    
    gameBootStrapper.init('gameDiv');
```

My index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="gameDiv">
    </div>    
</body>
<script src="client/lib/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src ="client/main.js"></script>
```

Here there is a picture of `index.html`:
........................................................

[image: Image of console]

Comment: What do you see if you console.log(game) just after var game = ...

Comment: i see the game object with everything inside it

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j2jzty

Comment: This means that game becomes undefined in the meantime. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the scope and context.

You are calling `init` from the context of `gameBootStrapper`, and the variable `game` does not exists within that context. In other words, I think you need to also pass the `game` variable into the `init` function in order for the gameBootStrapper object to be able to reach that variable. So something like this:

```
var gameBootStrapper = {
     init:function(gameContainerId, game){
         game.state.add('main', main);
         game.state.start('main');
     }
};    
gameBootStrapper.init('gameDiv', game);
```

You could also bind the `init` to a different context somehow, though I forget how to do that. I must say that I find scoping and context in JavaScript to be tricky and unintuitive IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how i solved it. It happen that i was using 'phaser 3' which is now uses `game.scene` instead of `game.start`. So i just changed the start to scene and it worked.